# XML error completing a multi-part upload to S3 with AWS SDK for JavaScript v3

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

A multi-part upload to S3 is divided in 3 steps:

- Initiate the multi-part upload
- Upload parts
- Complete the multi-part upload

Using [AWS SDK for JavaScript v3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/index.html) (exactly v3.22), the first two steps are successful:

- The `UploadId` comes from the initialisation.
- Each part upload comes with its `ETag` needed to complete the
  upload.

The issue comes requesting the upload completion, that is done with:

```
  const completeParams: CompleteMultipartUploadCommandInput = {
    Bucket,
    Key,
    UploadId,
    MultipartUpload: { Parts },
  };
  return client.send(new CompleteMultipartUploadCommand(completeParams));
```

Where `Parts` is an array of valid `CompletedPart` objects sorted by `PartNumber`.

Analysing the network call, the request is done to

```
https://{Bucket}.s3.{Location}.scw.cloud/{Key}?uploadId={UploadId}&x-id=CompleteMultipartUpload
```

*Note: replaced sensible data with placeholders, but they are the expected values.*

And the body generated by the AWS SDK is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CompletedMultipartUpload xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
  <Part>
    <ETag>&quot;610c4...&quot;</ETag>
    <PartNumber>1</PartNumber>
  </Part>
  <Part>
    <ETag>&quot;2edb4...&quot;</ETag>
    <PartNumber>2</PartNumber>
  </Part>
</CompletedMultipartUpload>
```

*Note: showing just the first 5 chars of each ETag to show that they are different and came from uploading parts.*

But the answer from S3 is:

```
The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema.
```

Sequence of calls:
[image]

Reading the [extensive documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CompleteMultipartUpload.html), there is a subtle difference: the root element of the XML should be `CompleteMultipartUpload` instead of `CompletedMultipartUpload`, but the XML is generated by the AWS SDK and I would expect it to be right.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Issue

This is an [open issue at aws-sdk-js-v3 official repository.](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/2445)

The error is, indeed, a typo on a XML element. It must be `CompleteMultipartUpload` instead of `CompletedMultipartUpload` (extra **d**).

### Workaround

Using a middleware that replaces the invalid XML tag, like this:

```js
const patchS3CompleteMultipartUpload = (client: S3Client): void => {
  client.middlewareStack.add(
    (next, _context) => (args: any) => {
      if ('string' === typeof args.request?.body && args.request.body.includes('CompletedMultipartUpload')) {
        args.request.body = args.request.body.replace(/CompletedMultipartUpload/g, 'CompleteMultipartUpload');
      }
      return next(args);
    },
    {
      step: 'build',
      priority: 'high',
    }
  );
};
```